# Unit Test for a Java Component accessing ActiveMq in Mule Flow

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mule, activemq-classic, mule-component

I have the below Java Class which retrieve messages from JMS queue. This class is invoked in a mule flow. Could you please advice on how I can write a Junit for this class? I have tried to create a standalone broker but I am having trouble

```
public Object getMessages(final MuleEventContext eventContext)
{
    final String consumerID = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("consumerID", PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
    final String messageSelector = "ConsumerID = '" + consumerID + "'";

    JmsConnector amqConnector = (JmsConnector) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupConnector("Active_MQ");
    ConnectionFactory factory = amqConnector.getConnectionFactory();
    Connection connection = null;

    List<String> listOfMessages = null;

    try
    {
        connection = factory.createConnection();            

        //Consumer Settings
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(queuename");            
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, messageSelector);            

        //Browser Settings
        Session sessionBrowser = amqConnector.getSession( false, false );
        Queue queueBrowser = sessionBrowser.createQueue( queuename );
        QueueBrowser qBrowser = sessionBrowser.createBrowser( queueBrowser, messageSelector );
        Enumeration<Message> enumeration = qBrowser.getEnumeration();
        connection.start();

        listOfMessages = new ArrayList<String>();           

        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements())
        {
            enumeration.nextElement();
            Message message = consumer.receive();
            TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;          
            listOfMessages.add(msg.getText());

         }



        //Close Browser Settings
        qBrowser.close(); sessionBrowser.close();
        //Close Consumer Settings
        consumer.close(); session.close();
        //Close Connection
        connection.close();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to retrieve messages from Queue "+ e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create FunctionalTestCase, and then:

- Test the class directly by calling the method, or
- Test the whole scenario by calling the flow

  ```
  public class MessageServiceTest extends FunctionalTestCase {

      @Test
      public void testJavaClass() throws Exception {
          MuleEventContext eventContext = MuleTestUtils.getTestEventContext("", MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE, muleContext); 

          MessageService messageService = new MessageService();
          assertNotNull(messageService.getMessages(eventContext));
      }

      @Test
      public void testFlow() throws Exception {
          MuleEvent event = runFlow("messageserviceFlow");
          MuleMessage message = event.getMessage();

          assertNotNull(message);
          assertNotNull(message.getPayload());
      }

      protected String getConfigResources() {
          return "messageservice.xml";
      }

  }
  ```